# How to find the status of a container using prometheus?

Tags: docker, monitoring, prometheus, cadvisor

[image]

I want to get status of a container using cadvisor and prometheus.
I know that I can get the created time using

```
time() - container_start_time_seconds{name="container_name"}
```

Is there any method to find the status of a container?

Answer (score -1):

You can just do `up` on PromQL

1 means up, and 0 means down.

[image: image demo]

Comment: That does not give the status of a container but the status of a job. I may have one advisor job for many containers.